# Change name of Singles

Tags: config, singles

Is there an updated version for Craft 3 showing how to change the name of 'Singles' and 'Structures'? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObC4mhXjiOE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a /translations/ folder to your project root and within that folder a /fill-in-locale-here/ folder. Add a file "app.php" to that /translations/fill-in-locale-here/ folder which returns an array of those translations. Here's an example => [view screenshot](https://cl.ly/6e5132433d70)